# Awk script for the /etc/shadow file : I need to know how to display it on one line

Tags: linux, awk

Trying to write an if statement inside an `awk` script that displays information from the shadow file.

So far I got:

```
/atrauger1/{print "Account Will Be Disabled";if ($7 == "")print "0"
```

It works exactly how I want it to but I need to know how to display it on one line.

Answer (score 2):

Option one: print it with one print statement.

```
print "Account will be disabled", ($7 == "") ? "0" : "";
```

Option two: print with `printf` to avoid line feeds being inserted automatically:

```
printf "Account will be disabled";
if ($7 == "") printf "0";
printf "\n";
```

Comment: Wow thanks!  It worked perfectly.  This is the first time I've ever posted a question online so to be honest i was a bit skeptical about it.